# error deploying django 2.0 to heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-2.0

I have created my first `Django 2.0` project and trying to deploy it into `Heroku`.

I have have setup all and all push and pull goes well.

But when I access my application endpoint with

```
https://jotitdown.herokuapp.com
```

It is not loading and `heroku logs` gives this error

```
2017-12-23T07:04:45.333450+00:00 heroku[router]: 
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" 
host=jotitdown.herokuapp.com request_id=cd2a9bb6-fae8-4317-af39-b271c1d74af5 
fwd="45.115.107.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I have set this in `settings.py`, here `

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', 'jotitdown.herokuapp.com', '*.herokuapp.com']
```

and `Profile`

`web: gunicorn notepad.wsgi --log-file -`

I tried running on local using

```
heroku local web
```

It gives error as

```
[WARN] No ENV file found
web.1   |  /bin/sh: gunicorn: command not found
web.1   Exited with exit code 127
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing all installed packages and reinstalling them all using Pipenv.

To start Heroku local web, if you are using virtual environment of `pipenv` you need to run following commands.

```
pipenv run heroku local web
```

This answer may help someone using `pipenv`.

Answer (score 0):

[Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) isn't automatically provided by Heroku. Your local copy is clearly missing it, and I suspect it's missing on Heroku as well.

Add it to your `requirements.txt` and install it locally, then test with `heroku local` again. Assuming that works, commit that change to `requirements.txt` and push to Heroku again.